# Just installed expo for the first time, get error immediately after initialisation

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

I am following the steps contained here
`https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started`

Ive installed a fresh copy of npm and even done `npm update` command

I then ran `npm install -g expo-cli`

This gave a whole bunch of warnings about linux packages not installed but im running Windows 10 Home 64bit so no probs there

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I then typed `expo init HelloWorld` and got the following error

```
C:\Users\####\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �d��.�
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
Uncaught Error C:\Users\####\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �d��.�
                                                              ^
   SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

I have no idea why. Its a clean install, is there something ive missed installing?

Comment: have u installed Node ?

Comment: Yes I have installed Node

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Syntax error: Invalid or unexpected token" running a script with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334643/syntax-error-invalid-or-unexpected-token-running-a-script-with-node-js)

Comment: Similar it seems yes. But what I have done is use npm to install formidable on its own and then overright the formidable that expo downloaded itself. seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used `npm install formidable` and then copied the resulting folder into the spot where expo has its copy of `formidable` which has fixed the problem.